# maxmind free geoip DB returns wrong country

Tags: php, laravel-5, geolocation, maxmind

I am using maxmind free DB (geoip.mmdb) and I have a script that update it to latest on daily basis, however, yesterday I noticed it started to return wrong countries by IP Address.

an IP address in Jordan (80.10.53.78).

for example:

```
$location = GeoIP::getLocation("80.10.53.78");
```

returns the following response

```
["ip" => "80.10.53.78",
 "isoCode" => "FR",
 "country" => "France",
 "city" => null,
 "state" => null,
 "postal_code" => null,
 "lat" => 48.8582,
 "lon" => 2.3387,
 "timezone" => "Europe/Paris",
 "continent" => "EU",
 "default" => false,
 ]
```

double checking on https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo , it returned the correct country. being Jordan.

How to fix this?

Comment: Their free DB can be not up to date. In MaxMind you can register for a Trial account. So that you get 1000 queries FREE for their Online API. 

Note: You cant register with free email domains. 

Try to go with Web service calls since it is always up to date.

Comment: Thanks @masterFly actually, the issue is that it was working just fine until lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. I work at MaxMind and we are working on a fix for the issue you have raised and expect to post updated GeoLite databases later today.

Comment: Thank you @thomas-mather I wish you update us on this thread so everyone is aware as well.

Comment: The updated GeoLite databases have been uploaded to our servers. Could you try downloading again? If you still see the issue, please let me know.

Comment: I have already fetched it and all looks goods. Thanks Alot @thomas-mather

Comment: @ThomasMather im facing similar issue, trying to get the country details using ip (111.92.51.2) India, showing correct data in your demo site, but getting 
  geoiprecord Object
(
    [country_code] => GB
    [country_code3] => GBR
    [country_name] => United Kingdom
    [region] => H9
    [city] => London
    [postal_code] => EC4N
    [latitude] => 51.5092
    [longitude] => -0.095499999999987
    [area_code] => 
    [dma_code] => 
    [metro_code] => 
    [continent_code] => EU
)